# TypeError: Cannot find function forEach in object

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, typeerror

I'm trying to create a cache for retrieving XML data.

My problem is im getting an error "TypeError: Cannot find function forEach in object"

I dont understand why im getting the error and i copied most of this out from an example.

The error occurs at:

```
 priceIDs.forEach (function (row) {
 row.forEach ( function (cell) {
  if (typeof(cell) === 'number' ) {
    dirtyTypeIDs.push(cell);
  }
 });
 });
```

The line "row.forEach ( function (cell) {" appears to be the culprit. I will post the whole of the code below for people to help :)

```
function LoadPrices(priceIDs, systemID,cacheBuster){

if (typeof systemID == "undefined") {
systemID=30000142;
}

if (typeof priceIDs == "undefined") {
throw "need typeids";
}

if (typeof cacheBuster == "undefined") {
cacheBuster=1;
}

var prices = new Array();
var dirtyTypeIDs = new Array();
var cleanTypeIDs = new Array();

var url = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?cacheBuster="+cacheBuster+"&usesystem="+systemID+"&typeid=";

priceIDs.forEach (function (row) {
row.forEach ( function (cell) {
  if (typeof(cell) === 'number' ) {
    dirtyTypeIDs.push(cell);
  }
});
});

cleanTypeIDs = dirtyTypeIDs.filter(function(v,i,a) {
return a.indexOf(v)===i;
});

var parameters = {method : "get",payload: ""};

var xmlFeed = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+cleanTypeIDs.join("&typeid="),parameters).getContent();
var xml = XmlService.parse(xmlFeed);  

if(xml)
{
var rows=xml.getRootElement().getChild("marketstat").getChildren("type");
for(var i = 0; i< rows.length; i++) {
  var price = [rows[i].getAttribute("id").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("sell").getChild("volume").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("sell").getChild("avg").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("sell").getChild("max").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("sell").getChild("min").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("sell").getChild("stddev").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("sell").getChild("median").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("sell").getChild("percentile").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("buy").getChild("min").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("buy").getChild("avg").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("buy").getChild("max").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("buy").getChild("min").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("buy").getChild("stddev").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("buy").getChild("median").getValue(),
  rows[i].getChild("buy").getChild("percentile").getValue(),
];
prices.push(price);
}
};
}
```

Can any help me understand the error and correct it?

Comment: Ensure that `row` is an array, `forEach()` is an Array method.

Comment: Can you show `priceIDs`?

Comment: Are you sure that this is an array element you are using the forEach on? The browser may not support forEach. You may need a polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Your `row` variable is actually an Object, so you can't use `forEach`. You can use this code to iterate `row` properly:

```
for (var column in row) {
    if (row.hasOwnProperty(column)) {
        var cell = row[column];

        if (typeof cell == "number") {
            dirtyTypeIDs.push(cell);
        }
    }
}
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735184/3402854).

---

**Long answer:**

A [`TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) is something that happens when you attempt to access a property of an Object, but the property is missing.

In the first case, you ask `priceIDs` (an **Array**) to call its `forEach` function. It does this happily, giving you the result you need (`row`).

However, in the second case, you ask `row` (an **Object**) to call its `forEach` function. `row` doesn't know anything called `forEach`, so it dies immediately.

To iterate properties of an Object, you need to use a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop. The code above will take `row`, iterate the appropriate properties, and push their values to `dirtyTypeIDs` based on the logic you provided. The question linked below the code answers why the `hasOwnProperty` check is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

the function "forEach" is the function for Array object. you can also find the browser compatibility with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach