# Google Sheets - A pull data function doesn't want to play nice with a history storing function

Tags: google-sheets, compiler-errors

I found a couple of functions that met my needs, but they don't want to play nice together. The goal is to pull data once a day, then add it to a new column. The history function is fine, and I've got a trigger setup to run it once a day, but it's erroring when attempting to run automatically, and sending me an email with the following.

```
6/18/18 5:29 PM loadRegionAggregates    TypeError: Cannot find function
forEach in object [object Object]. (line 19, file
"Code") time-based  6/18/18 5:29 PM
```

here's the full code.gs (I bolded the section with line 19, first line of the function)

```
// Requires a list of typeids, so something like Types!A:A
// https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IixV0eNqg19FE6cLzb83G1Ucb0Otl-Jnvm6csAlPKwo/edit?usp=sharing for an example

function loadRegionAggregates(priceIDs,regionID){
  if (typeof regionID == 'undefined'){
    regionID=10000002;
  }
  if (typeof priceIDs == 'undefined'){
    throw 'Need a list of typeids';

  }

  var prices = new Array();
  var dirtyTypeIds = new Array();
  var cleanTypeIds = new Array();

  var url="https://market.fuzzwork.co.uk/aggregates/?station=60003760&types=34,35,36,37,38,39,40"

  **priceIDs.forEach(function (row) {
    row.forEach(function (cell) {
     if (typeof(cell) === 'number' ) {
        dirtyTypeIds.push(cell);
      }**
    });
  });
  cleanTypeIds = dirtyTypeIds.filter(function(v,i,a) {
    return a.indexOf(v)===i;
  });

  prices.push(['TypeID','Buy volume','Buy Weighted Average','Max Buy','Min Buy','Buy Std Dev','Median Buy','Percentile Buy Price','Sell volume','Sell Weighted Average','Max sell','Min Sell','Sell Std Dev','Median Sell','Percentile Sell Price'])
  var parameters = {method : "get", payload : ""};

  var o,j,temparray,chunk = 100;
  for (o=0,j=cleanTypeIds.length; o < j; o+=chunk) {
    temparray = cleanTypeIds.slice(o,o+chunk);
    Utilities.sleep(100);
    var types=temparray.join(",").replace(/,$/,'')
    var jsonFeed = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+types, parameters).getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(jsonFeed);
    if(json) {
      for(i in json) {
        var price=[parseInt(i),
                   parseInt(json[i].buy.volume),
                   parseInt(json[i].buy.weightedAverage),
                   parseFloat(json[i].buy.max),
                   parseFloat(json[i].buy.min),
                   parseFloat(json[i].buy.stddev),
                   parseFloat(json[i].buy.median),
                   parseFloat(json[i].buy.percentile),
                   parseInt(json[i].sell.volume),
                   parseFloat(json[i].sell.weightedAverage),
                   parseFloat(json[i].sell.max),
                   parseFloat(json[i].sell.min),
                   parseFloat(json[i].sell.stddev),
                   parseFloat(json[i].sell.median),
                   parseFloat(json[i].sell.percentile)];
        prices.push(price);
      }
    }
  }
  return prices;
}

function storeData() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
 var numRows = datarange.getNumRows();
 var numColumns = datarange.getNumColumns();

 sheet.getRange(1,numColumns + 1).setValue(new Date());

  for (var i=2; i <= numRows; i++) {

    var prices = sheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue();

    sheet.getRange(i, numColumns + 1).setValue(prices);
  }
}
```

I found this link: 
[TypeError: Cannot find function forEach in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307156/typeerror-cannot-find-function-foreach-in-object)

Which explains some of it, but when the code runs in debug mode, I don't have a range defined, and then the live sheet bugs with:

```
ReferenceError: "row" is not defined (line 21).
```

Note: My original code works fine when I run the script locally, just not when the daily timer goes off. I'm assuming the issues listed on the linked query regarding no forEach class on the nested object are applying to whatever runs the triggered .gs

Edit: Ok so i've been working on this all day. I've learned how to set an array var (since I didn't need to change the array, static works) and i've been trying to get the rest of the code adjusted ever since. Here's where I am so far:

```
// Requires a list of typeids, so something like Types!A:A
// https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IixV0eNqg19FE6cLzb83G1Ucb0Otl-Jnvm6csAlPKwo/edit?usp=sharing for an example

function loadRegionAggregates(priceIDs,regionID){
  if (typeof regionID == 'undefined'){
    regionID=10000002;
  }
  if (typeof priceIDs == 'undefined'){
    priceIDs = [34,35,36,37,38,39,40,11399];


  }


  var prices = new Array();
  var dirtyTypeIds = new Array();
  var cleanTypeIds = new Array();

  var url="https://market.fuzzwork.co.uk/aggregates/?station=60003760&types=34,35,36,37,38,39,40"


// for (var priceIDs) {
//    if (row.hasOwnProperty(column)) {
//        var cell = row[column];

//        if (typeof cell == "number") {
           priceIDs.push(priceIDs);
//        }
//    }

// }


  cleanTypeIds = dirtyTypeIds.filter(function(v,i,a) {
    return a.indexOf(v)===i;
  });

  prices.push(['TypeID','Buy volume','Buy Weighted Average','Max Buy','Min Buy','Buy Std Dev','Median Buy','Percentile Buy Price','Sell volume','Sell Weighted Average','Max sell','Min Sell','Sell Std Dev','Median Sell','Percentile Sell Price'])
  var parameters = {method : "get", payload : ""};

  var o,j,temparray,chunk = 100;
  for (o=0,j=cleanTypeIds.length; o < j; o+=chunk) {
    temparray = cleanTypeIds.slice(o,o+chunk);
    Utilities.sleep(100);
    var types=temparray.join(",").replace(/,$/,'')
    var jsonFeed = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+types, parameters).getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(jsonFeed);
    if(json) {
      for(i in json) {
        var price=[parseInt(i),
                   parseInt(json[i].buy.volume),
                   parseInt(json[i].buy.weightedAverage),
                   parseFloat(json[i].buy.max),
                   parseFloat(json[i].buy.min),
                   parseFloat(json[i].buy.stddev),
                   parseFloat(json[i].buy.median),
                   parseFloat(json[i].buy.percentile),
                   parseInt(json[i].sell.volume),
                   parseFloat(json[i].sell.weightedAverage),
                   parseFloat(json[i].sell.max),
                   parseFloat(json[i].sell.min),
                   parseFloat(json[i].sell.stddev),
                   parseFloat(json[i].sell.median),
                   parseFloat(json[i].sell.percentile)];
        prices.push(price);
      }
    }
  }
  return prices;
}



function storeData() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
 var numRows = datarange.getNumRows();
 var numColumns = datarange.getNumColumns();

 sheet.getRange(1,numColumns + 1).setValue(new Date());

  for (var i=2; i <= numRows; i++) {

    var prices = sheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue();

    sheet.getRange(i, numColumns + 1).setValue(prices);
  }
}
```

So far, so good. It's not throwing any more errors on debug, and the column headers are coming in, but it's not bringing in the data anymore from the push.

Help!

Comment: Can you log `priceIDs`?

Comment: maybe? Currently I have them on a seperate tab and use them in the function call (A:A)

Comment: can you add the function call?